# log4j2.xml sys vs env on Desktop application and in Tomcat Webapp

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat7, environment-variables, log4j2

I have both a dekstop application and a tomcat web application that write to a log file using `log4j2`. I also then have the `log4j2.xml` configuration file. The file it is writing to is held within a folder that as stored as an `environment variable`. The `log4j2.xml` file thus looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">

    <Properties>

        <Property name="logdir">${env:FOO}/log</Property>

        <Property name="msgformat">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{GMT+0} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Property>

    </Properties>

    <Appenders>

        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">

            <PatternLayout pattern="${msgformat}"/>

        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="ERROR_FILE" fileName="${logdir}/error.log"

            filePattern="${logdir}/error-%i.log">

            <PatternLayout pattern="${msgformat}"/>

            <Policies>

                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>

            </Policies>

            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>

        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="EVENT_FILE" fileName="${logdir}/event.log"

            filePattern="${logdir}/event-%i.log">

            <PatternLayout pattern="${msgformat}"/>

            <Policies>

                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>

            </Policies>

            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>

        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="foo.utils.footest" level="trace"

            additivity="false">

            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>

        </Logger>       

        <Logger name="foo.foologger" level="trace"

            additivity="false">

            <AppenderRef ref="ERROR_FILE" level="WARN"/>

            <AppenderRef ref="EVENT_FILE" level="TRACE"/>

        </Logger>       

        <Logger name="foo" level="info"

            additivity="false">

            <AppenderRef ref="ERROR_FILE" level="WARN"/>

            <AppenderRef ref="EVENT_FILE" level="TRACE"/>

        </Logger>   

        <Root level="trace">

            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />

        </Root>

    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

However when I try to use that `log4j2.xml` with the Tomcat webapp it just created a `${env:FOO}` folder in the `file-system` directory. However of I replace `env` with `sys` then the webapp writes to the log file but now when the Desktop application tries to use that `log4j2.xml` with `sys` it make a `${sys:FOO}` folder in the `file-system` directory. Why might this be happening, where when I use `sys` with the desktop app it can't find the environment variable but the webapp can and when I use `env` the webapp can't find the environment variable but the desktop app can? I am using `log4j2` with `tomcat 7.0.57` with `RHEL 6.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is put the environment variables you want to use in the `seten.sh` file in the tomcat bin. After you do this, when tomcat starts it will load that environment variable and you will be able to find that variable using the `env` designation in the `log4j2.xml` file.